# Convert from a UArray to a StorableArray

Tags: arrays, haskell, image-processing

I'm using [JuicyPixels](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/JuicyPixels/1.0/doc/html/Codec-Picture-Types.html#t%3aImage) to load PNGs fron on-disk, and I need a pointer to the raw pixel data. It is stored as a UArray in JuicyPixels. How do I get said pointer? Is it as simple as "casting" to a StorableArray? If so, how?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning JuicyPixels! I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`thaw`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-MArray.html#v%3athaw) in `IO`:

```
do storableArray <- thaw uArray
   ...
```

This copies the entire array, but probably more efficiently than hand-written code to do the same. If you know you're not going to access the `UArray` again, then you can use [`unsafeThaw`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-MArray.html#v%3aunsafeThaw), but with current library implementations, it's still likely to cause a complete copy. (The array types that have a non-copying implementation of `unsafeThaw` are listed in its documentation.)

There might be an unportable way to get at the raw pointer underlying a `UArray`, but I couldn't find one in [`GHC.Exts`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/GHC-Exts.html).